# Async method to API adjusts variable and then afterwards the variable is in its original state

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

Alright so I use an eID-cardreader to get Name etc from an ID-card and then I use the following method
to look if there's already someone in the database with the exact same info:

```
    private async void GetCustomer()
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:32576/api/customer?name=" + EIDCustomer.CustomerName + "&address=" + EIDCustomer.Address);
            if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                ApplicationVM.customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(json);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("api fail");
            }
        }
    }
```

Alright so `ApplicationVM.customer` is the following: "`public static Customer customer = null;`"
`GetCustomer()` is being called in the following method:

```
private Customer GetCustomerFromIDReader()
{
    Customer c = new Customer();

    try
    {
        //BEID_ReaderSet.initSDK();
        BEID_ReaderSet readerSet = BEID_ReaderSet.instance();
        BEID_ReaderContext reader = readerSet.getReader();

        if(reader.isCardPresent())
        {
            BEID_EIDCard card = reader.getEIDCard();
            BEID_EId doc = card.getID();

            string firstName = doc.getFirstName();
            string lastName = doc.getSurname();
            int postCode = Int32.Parse(doc.getZipCode());
            string straatEnNr = doc.getStreet().Trim();
            string gemeente = doc.getMunicipality();
            c.CustomerName = firstName + "" + lastName;
            c.Address = straatEnNr + ";" + postCode + ";" + gemeente;
            c.Picture = card.getPicture().getData().GetBytes();
        }
        else
        {
            c = null;
        }

        BEID_ReaderSet.releaseSDK();
    }
    catch (BEID_Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write("Er is iets misgelopen bij het inlezen van de eID");
        return null;
    }

    EIDCustomer = c;

    GetCustomer();

    return c;
}
```

EIDCustomer is a property of the type Customer. Alright so then the program is supposed to check if c is null, if it's not then it checks if ApplicationVM.customer is null. If so you get redirected to a window where you're asked to make a new account. If ApplicationVM.customer is not null, you get to go to the next window. This is the code:

```
public ICommand LoginCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand(Login);
    }
}

public void Login()
{
    ApplicationVM appvm = App.Current.MainWindow.DataContext as ApplicationVM;

    Customer c = new Customer();

    c = GetCustomerFromIDReader();

    if(c == null)
    {
        Console.Write("Er is iets fout gelopen bij het inlezen van de e-IDkaart");
    }
    else if (ApplicationVM.customer == null)
    {
        appvm.ChangePage(typeof(KlantNieuwVM));
    }
    else
    {
        appvm.ChangePage(typeof(KlantenInterfaceVM));
    }
}
```

( I work with UserControls to change pages, I'm always on MainWindow, but I don't think that's of any importance to the question. )

This is the method being called in the API:

```
public Customer Get(string name, string address)
{
    return CustomerDA.CheckCustomerLogin(name, address);
}
```

`CustomerDA.CheckCustomerLogin` is just an sql statement which checks if there's someone in the database with the exact same name and address.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing is that your `GetCustomer()` method is asynchronous and you are not awaiting it. So when you hit the `HttpResponseMessage` line:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("");
```

control is returned to your command and execution continues prior to the request coming back.

You can fix this by making your command async.

When you use the async/await pattern, the entire call chain needs to be awaitable, or else you will have this problem.

#### GetCustomerFromIDReader

```
private async Task<Customer> GetCustomerFromIDReader()
{
    Customer c = new Customer();

    // .... redacted for clarity

    await GetCustomer();

    return c;
}
```

#### Command usage

```
public ICommand LoginCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand(async () => await Login());
    }
}

public async Task Login()
{
    ApplicationVM appvm = App.Current.MainWindow.DataContext as ApplicationVM;

    Customer c = new Customer();

    c = await GetCustomerFromIDReader();

    if(c == null)
    {
        Console.Write("Er is iets fout gelopen bij het inlezen van de e-IDkaart");
    }
    else if (ApplicationVM.customer == null)
    {
        appvm.ChangePage(typeof(KlantNieuwVM));
    }
    else
    {
        appvm.ChangePage(typeof(KlantenInterfaceVM));
    }
}
```

Lastly change your `GetCustomer` to return a Task and not be void.

#### GetCustomer

```
private async Task GetCustomer()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("");
        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            ApplicationVM.customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(json);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("api fail");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I explain in my [MSDN article on async best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), avoid `async void`.

So, your `async void` method should be `async Task`:

```
private async Task GetCustomerAsync()
{
  ...
}
```

And when it's called, it should be `await`ed, which in turn makes the calling method `async`:

```
private async Task<Customer> GetCustomerFromIDReaderAsync()
{
  ...

  EIDCustomer = c;

  await GetCustomerAsync();

  return c;
}
```

And the same with the method that calls that one:

```
public async Task LoginAsync()
{
  ApplicationVM appvm = App.Current.MainWindow.DataContext as ApplicationVM;

  Customer c = new Customer();

  c = await GetCustomerFromIDReaderAsync();

  if(c == null)
  {
    Console.Write("Er is iets fout gelopen bij het inlezen van de e-IDkaart");
  }
  else if (ApplicationVM.customer == null)
  {
    appvm.ChangePage(typeof(KlantNieuwVM));
  }
  else
  {
    appvm.ChangePage(typeof(KlantenInterfaceVM));
  }
}
```

Finally, you end up with the `ICommand` implementation, where you *could* use `async void` (since it is logically an event handler):

```
public ICommand LoginCommand
{
  get
  {
    return new RelayCommand(async () => { await LoginAsync(); });
  }
}
```

However, you'll want to consider several points when dealing with asynchronous commands. This simple example will not disable the `ICommand` while it is executing, nor will it handle exceptions cleanly. I have another [MSDN article specifically on asynchronous MVVM commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx).

Comment: I have managed to solve it changing up the GetCustomer method to this: http://pastebin.com/GhT6wizr . I'm not sure if this is bad practice though (besides the async void).

Comment: @Pieter-JanVandenbussche: Yes, that's definitely a bad practice. If you want to download synchronously, just use `WebClient`.